# Mixamo rig bones are messed up when imported to blender

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, import, .fbx

I got a model and a rig from mixamo and when i import it into blender all the bones are pointing upwards. Tried importing it with "!EXPERIMENTAL! Apply Transform" but it didnt fix it. when importing i tried it with "Automatic Bone Orientation" and it fixed almost everything except the toe bones.

[image: Normal Import]

[image: With Automatic Bone Orientation]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Can't you just rotate the toe bones by yourself? What exactly is your question?

Comment: @palkonimo Thank you, If i edit it manually will motion capture files still work? And why is it doing so? gave it to a friend and he tried it with 3ds max and it works fine.

Comment: Did you already try the motion capture files? With and without rotating the toes manually? I don't see a reason for it not to work.

Answer (score 4):

ive found a solution. 
These 3 boxes need to be CHECKED.

1. !Experimental! Apply Transform
2. Force Connect Children
3. Automatic Bone Rotation.

im using Blender 2.81.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what seem to work fine with Blender 3.0.1:

[image]